# What are the newest Play service Version?

Tags: android, google-play-services

At the moment I compile my App with this line `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'` and so I use the Version 4.2.42 of the play services, but which are the newest?
Is there any page where I can find this out?
**

**EDIT:**

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3'
```

with this line I got e problem that this can't become compiled, why?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html

Comment: Is it possible that i have to change somethin in my code with adview etc.?

Comment: "but which are the newest?" -- At the time of this writing, ["Gradle, please"](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/) is reporting that it is 4.3.23.